# How make a firemonkey button with transparent graphic, and make it the default style

Tags: delphi, button, delphi-xe, transparent, firemonkey

With firemonkey I'm lost in how do some basic stuff.

I already know that I need to put a TImageControl inside the TButton to show a image.

However, the TImageControl is show with a border and a white background. I load inside a ico and/or png and wanna show it transparent, and wanna this for the whole app.

What are the steps for do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `TImage` instead of `TImageControl`. TImage is transparent by default. Of course, if your image isn't rectangular, you'll want to load an image that supports alpha channel, such as a PNG image.

If you insist on a TImageControl, right-click on it, select "Edit Custom Style..." and on the background TRectangle, set it's Fill color from `claWhite` to `claNull` and click `Apply and Close`. For any additional TImageControl, set its StyleLookup property to the same.

You'll also want to turn off the HitTest property of the image control.

Comment: You might also consider creating a new FireMonkey component so that you can simply add new 'TImageButtons' from your toolbar on to your applications rather than editing the StyleLookup for every button you add.

See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_a_FireMonkey_Component